# Blueimp : empty file upload result for video files

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, blueimp

Here's the plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I could upload images , but I'm getting this result when I try to upload video. I allowed all file type.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: 'url',

        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        maxFileSize: 9222299000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$/i
    });
```

Comment: `this` result being?

Comment: "empty file upload result"

Comment: Could you add the html?

Comment: not allowing more code . But It's the same like [DEMO](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery-file-upload library requires JSON response in a very [specific format](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/JSON-Response).

It's possible that your formatting is wrong for video files, which would be causing the problem

Comment: I didn't understand.I'm trying to upload mp4 files.what's wrong with that?acceptFileTypes?  what should i do?